# recycleview onBindView & onViewAttachedToWindow duplicate confused

Tags: android, android-viewholder

The following is the code of recycleview.adapter:

```
private class MyRecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private  MyRecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder=null;

    @Override
    public MyRecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate( R.layout.device_tmperature,parent,false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onBindView position " + position+" suppose to be seen "+holder.getLayoutPosition()+" ℃" );
        viewHolder.degree.setText(holder.getLayoutPosition()+" ℃");
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }



    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onViewAttachedToWindow position " + holder.getLayoutPosition()+" suppose to be seen "+holder.getLayoutPosition()+" ℃" );
        viewHolder.degree.setText(holder.getLayoutPosition()+" ℃");

    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView degree = null;
        CardView cv_device=null;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            degree= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_degree);
            cv_device = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_device);
            cv_device.setCardElevation(5);
            cv_device.setRadius(5);
        }
    }
}
```

At first, it was correct, but when I slide down, it displayed "6℃" at position 4, while it is supposed to be "5℃". And the following are confused too.

Comment: Why you want to do the same in onBindViewHolder and onViewAttachedToWindow?

Comment: Remove the code from `onViewAttachedToWindow()`. You shouldn't ever have to use this method except for very special circumstances.

Comment: @ResolutioN I had tried to make it works, but it didn't help

Comment: @Karakuri I've tried it, it didn't work. Thanks anyway

Comment: Maybe you should use `holder.getAdapterPosition()` instead.

Comment: @Karakuri I've already triesd. :(

Comment: How about just `position` then?

Comment: @Karakuri I fixed it. It supposed to use holder rather than viewholder...Thank you for your patience and help all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,I work it out.It was supposed to use holder rather than viewholder.